# rendering n-point polygon with face in 3D

Tags: three.js

Newbie to three.js. I have multiple n-sided polygons to be displayed as faces (I want the polygon face to be opaque). Each polygon is facing a different direction in 3D space (essentially theses faces are part of some building).

Here are a couple of methods I tried, but they do not fit the bill:

1. Used Geometry object and added the n-vertices and used line mesh. It created the polygon as a hollow polygon. As my number of points are not just 3 or 4, I could not use the Face3 or Face4 object. Essentially a Face-n object.
2. I looked at the WebGL geometric shapes example. The shape object works in 2D and extrusion. All the objects in the example are on one plane. While my requirement is each polygon has a different 3D normal vector. Should I use 2D shape and also take note of the face normal and rotate the 2D shape after rendering.

Or is there a better way to render multiple 3D flat polygons with opaque faces with just x, y, z vertices.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your polygons are convex you can still use the Face3 object. If you take one n-sided polygon, lets say a hexagon, you can create Face3 polygons by taking vertices numbered (0,1,2) as one face, vertices (0,2,3) as another face, vertices (0,3,4) as other face and vertices (0,4,5) as last face. I think you can get the idea if you draw it on paper. But this works only for convex polygons.